# NSDraggingSession swallows up all NSEvents

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I specifically want to know when NSFlagChanged event occurs during a @(draggingSession:movedToPoint:). Are there any ways to find out considering the selector @(flagsChanged:) is never called during the drag session?

Edit: Neither the NSApplication, nor the NSWindow receives an @(sendEvent:).

Comment: Check `NSApp.currentEvent.modifierFlags` in `draggingUpdated`?

Comment: I can check for modifiers but what I really want is to know *when* they were changed. And of course, I can't check when there are no mouse movement in the middle of a drag so @(draggingsession::) isn't called.

Comment: `draggingUpdated` is called periodically. `currentEvent` can be a FlagsChanged event. NSWindow's `sendEvent` is called when I push the Shift, Option, Control or Command key. Do you want to drag inside or outside your app?

Comment: It is within the application from one view to another. @(draggingUpdated) is a NSDraggingDestination so it won't get called until I go to the destination view. I still would like to get flags changed even when I'm not yet over the destination, which is why I was hopping the NSDraggingSource had some way of doing it.